# DocuSign for Salesforce: how to pass void reason when voiding an envelope via a custom button?

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

window.location.href='/apex/dsfs__DocuSignVoidEnvelopeStandAlone?e=envelopeid'

how do i pass the reason text as well as a parameter to dsfs__DocuSignVoidEnvelopeStandAlone

Comment: The subject doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I clarified the subject line. Unfortunately I don't know the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no button parameter for Void Reason as the out of the box Void Envelope button included in the Manage Package sends you to a form POST.

It is possible with APEX to call the DocuSign API directly and build in a void reason, it's been covered in [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25002920/how-do-i-programatically-void-a-docusign-envelope-in-salesforce)