# Docusign for Salesforce Void Button - Passing Envelope ID

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I'm creating a custom void button in the lead object, but I can't seem to pass the envelope ID, the test lead does have an envelope attached/associated.

Is there a built-in method in "docusign.js" to get or retrieve the DSEID?

My button js code:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_JavaScript")}

window.location.href='/apex/dsfs__DocuSignVoidEnvelopeStandAlone?e={!dsfs__DocuSign_Envelope__c.dsfs__DocuSign_Envelope_ID__c}';
```

Comment: Which docusign.js are you referring to? Can you please add a link to the file.

Comment: I actually don't know what the file is, that's why I used quotation marks, I know it's being requested here "{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_JavaScript")}
"

Comment: I believe you can only Void from the DS Status object itself because multiple DS Statuses can be related to a record. I do believe you could do some custom APEX code to get it done (but that requires API Certification): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25002920/how-do-i-programatically-void-a-docusign-envelope-in-salesforce

Comment: Got it. I'll look into that. Thanks.